# How to organize a Cucumber feature file when there is a common "Then"?

Tags: cucumber, scenarios

I have the following two scenarios in my feature file:

```
@system-A @updating-dob
Scenario: Updating customers dob
  Given an account from system A
  When I save the dob
  Then I should see the dob is updated successfully

@system-B @updating-dob
Scenario: Updating customers dob
  Given an account from system B
  When I save the dob
  Then I should see the dob is updated successfully
```

As you can see I have two scenarios in the same file but only the `Given` is different. Is there a way I can combine these two scenarios using Scenario Outline?

BTW, the step definition for

```
  Given an account from system A
  Given an account from system B
```

is 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a scenario outline:

```
@updating-dob
Scenario Outline: Updating customer's dob
  Given an account from system <system>
  When I save the dob
  Then I should see the dob is updated successfully

Examples:
  | system |
  | A |
  | B |
```

You can't have @system-A on the example that tests system A and @system-B on the example that tests system B, however.

Comment: This worked great! thanks... I just dont like the fact that all of my tests has:```Examples:
  | system |
  | A |
  | B |```

Comment: Me neither. Unfortunately Cucumber definitely doesn't support reusing Examples.